# What's the differences between the weapons?

Tags: green-the-planet

You can have a laser, a missile, or a cannon type weapon. Each has different levels you can upgrade it to.

They all work slightly differently, but I am having trouble determining if one does more damage or if the differences are just cosmetic.

Are there differences in terms of damage or how often they will destroy the asteroids passing above?

Comment: Hmm, I just played the game for about 15 minutes and I have no trouble determining that the laser is superior... what kind of trouble are you encountering when trying to determine what blows up asteroids faster?